# How to make sure that both column values exists only once in database table?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, database-design

I have a table which stores the hash tags as a many to many relation ship

Tags Table

```
userID - Foreign key
tags - foreign key
```

I have used `Unique` constraint which I think is a foolish one.

Here I want to ensure that a user uses the tag a user uses each tag only once in that table.

What query will suit this scenario?

So the desired output is like a user uses only `one tag`

The database I use is PostgreSQL.
Since I use Django where I have the code below

```
user = models.ForeignKey("User",unique=True)
userTags = models.ForeignKey("Tags",unique=True)
```

which has a meaning of that

1. user column is foreign key reference from User table and it's a unique column
2. UserTags column is a foreign key reference from Tags table and that column is unique

Comment: A user "*uses only one tag*" is something completely different than "*a user uses each tag only once*" - so which one is it?

Comment: if the user can use only a single tag, then you should not have a N:M relationship here, I guess

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have you're right and I want `a user uses each tag only once`

Comment: Then the unique constraint you have on `(userid, tags)`  will do exactly that (assuming that `tags` - despite the plural - references a single tag in a different table)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But when I've used the constraint as `userid- unique=true and tags-unique=true` using this causes error when I tried to add another tag for the same user

Comment: That is not valid SQL. Please **[edit]** your question and add the actual DDL you used to create the constraints. And tell us which DBMS you are using MySQL and Postgres are two very different database products

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah! I have updated the question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A little help can make my day please!